# How to pass value Array to Get command

Tags: arrays, powershell

a portion of my code

```
$OldSub1 = "192.168.1.*"
$OldSub2 = "192.168.2.*"
$OldSub3 = "192.168.3.*"
$OldSub4 = "192.168.4.*"

$OldIp = Get-NetIpAddress | where {
($_.IPAddress -like $OldSub1) -or
($_.IPAddress -like $OldSub2) -or
($_.IPAddress -like $OldSub3) -or        
($_.IPAddress -like $OldSub4)
}
if ($OldIp.IPAddress -eq $null) {write "Null"}
$OldIp
```

I'd like to use an array, but I can't understand how, in this way I have no mistake but Oldip takes on value

```
$OldSubNets = @(
"192.168.1.*",
"192.168.2.*"
)
foreach ($i in $OldSubNets){
 if (-not($i -eq $null)){
 $OldIp = Get-NetIpAddress | where { $_.IPAddress -like $i }
 }
}
$OldIp
```

Comment: Here's a unique way to approach this `Get-NetIpAddress | ? { $OldSubnets -contains ($_.IPAdress -replace '\d+$', '*') }`

Comment: That's clever, @Abraham - you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @mklement0, thank you! I visit this site mainly on my phone now so I got too lazy to post it with an explanation:) lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Move the array-iteration loop into your `Where-Object` (`where`) block.
- Stop iterating and return `$true` once a match has been found.

```bash
# Note: A typo was corrected "Subents" -> "Subnets"
$OldSubnets = @(
"192.168.1.*",
"192.168.2.*"
)

$OldIp = 
  Get-NetIpAddress | Where-Object { 
    foreach ($i in $OldSubnets) {
      if ($_.IPAddress -like $i) { return $true }
    }
  }
```

---

You can streamline the solution if you use [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) instead of [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like): This enables using a [*regex*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), which allows you to test for multiple pattern at once, using alternation (`|`):

```bash
# Note: Do NOT use the "*" at the end.
$OldSubnetPrefixes = @(
  "192.168.1.",
  "192.168.2."
)

# Construct a regex from the prefixes.
$oldSubnetsRegex = 
  '^(?:{0})' -f ($OldSubnetPrefixes.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')

$OldIp = 
  Get-NetIpAddress | Where-Object IPAddress -match $oldSubnetsRegex
```

`$oldSubnetsRegex` receives the string `'^(?:192\.168\.1\.|192\.168\.2\.)'`, and it is obviously also an option to construct such a regex directly; for an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/Rp1tMh/1).

Also note the use of [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) in the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call.